# AS3 | Adobe AIR 3.4 Android: Laggy horizontal movement even at constant 60fps

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe

Ok, I've been working on a simple game for some days now. But object moving keep lagging even tho the games runs at 60fps.

I made a new project, with one object, a bitmap not a vector object, but still it can't move without lagg/sluggish behaviour.

Is there any reason for why on my LG Optimus 2X, a single object can't move (this.x -= 10) without "lagging/sluggish" behaviour? It works just fine on Samsung Galaxy S2.

EDIT: Test on: 
LG Optimus 2x, Sluggish.
Sony Xperia, Sluggish. 
Samsung Galaxy S2, Perfect. 
HTC Desire Z, Perfect.

Makes no sense? HTC Desire Z is far from faster than LG 2X!

Comment: Are you using the Starling framework?

Comment: No? What is Starling framework?

Comment: Starling is a 2D rendering framework that uses Stage3D, which employs direct hardware acceleration instead of traditional software rendered graphics on the stage display list. download: http://starling-framework.org/ docs: http://doc.starling-framework.org/core/